# How to run Batch file or cmd line from RIDE

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I am having the command line argument as like below:

```
python tokengen.py --authzSystemId default --macKey "01234567890123456789012345678901" --configurationId default --tokenExpiry 3600 --permission manageSystem --permission manageConfiguration
```

I need to run the `tokengen.py` file by passing all the arguments as above. I am able to do it from command line argument.

How to do it from ride are there are any keywords? If there please provide with syntax.

Thanks
Prasanth

Answer (score 0):

Im using just simple "run" keyword. In case of uncertainty this keyword is from `OperatingSystem.Run`.
So in ride it looks like:

`run` `cd C:\\test && C:\\test\\createfile`

Createfile is just simple bat file to create empty file.